# Change Interface Orientation from landScape to portrait by pressing a button

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to change Interface Orientation from landScape to portrait by pressing a button in cocos2dx v2 c++

Comment: What you have tried??

Answer (score 1):

Add a class variable

```
Bool isInLandsCapeOrientation;
```

in **viewDidLoad**

set this flag to

```
isInLandsCapeOrientation = false;
```

Add the following function

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 if (!isInLandsCapeOrientation) {
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation));

 }else {
     return  (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
 }
}
```

To changing orientation from portrait to landscape, let it happens on a button action

```
- (IBAction)changeOrientationButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
isInLandsCapeOrientation = true;
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```